# VueJS component not rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rendering, vue-component

I have a very basic VueJS app which I'm building by following the website.

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/43452/) the code, why is this component not rendering?

HTML:

```html
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    
    <div id="app">
      <p>{{ message }}</p>
    </div>
    
    <div>
    <ol>
      <todo-item></todo-item>
    </ol>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
      }
    })
    
    Vue.component('todo-item', {
        template: '<li>This is a list item</li>'
    })
```

Comment: Your `<todo-item>` is outside of `<div id="app">`, which is the Vue mount point.

Comment: @yuriy636 doesn't work even if I put my `<ol>` inside `div#app` .. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/43458/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Better, you can use the [Single File Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) to define the `todo-item` component inside another file:

*app.vue*

```
 import TodoItem from './components/todo-item'

 new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  },
  components: {
    TodoItem
  }
})
```

*components/todo-item.vue*

```
<template>
  <li>This is a list item</li>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'todo-item'
  }
</script>
```

> In many Vue projects, global components will be defined using `Vue.component`, followed by `new Vue({ el: '#container' })` to target a container element in the body of every page.
>
> This can work very well for small to medium-sized projects, where JavaScript is only used to enhance certain views. In more complex projects however, or when your frontend is entirely driven by JavaScript, these disadvantages become apparent:
>
> - **Global definitions** force unique names for every component
> - **String templates** lack syntax highlighting and require ugly slashes for multiline HTML
> - **No CSS support** means that while HTML and JavaScript are modularized into components, CSS is conspicuously left out
> - **No build step** restricts us to HTML and ES5 JavaScript, rather than preprocessors like Pug (formerly Jade) and Babel
>
> All of these are solved by single-file components with a `.vue` extension, made possible with build tools such as Webpack or Browserify.

Comment: That doesn't work in the Fiddle for me on Chrome. Do you think the Fiddle just loads Vue incorrectly?

Comment: I've added some explanations

Comment: `Vue.Component('...')` will declare the component globally. It's wrong to use `Vue.Component` inside `components {}`

Answer (score 54):

- Use the component **inside of the specified `el` mount element**
- Define the component **before** initializing the Vue instance with `new Vue`

```js
Vue.component('todo-item', {
  template: '<li>This is a list item</li>'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ol>
    <todo-item></todo-item>
  </ol>
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
</div>

<div>

</div>
```

Comment: This one is the correct answer. And according to the doc, it's indeed required to declare component BEFORE instantiating Vue :)

Comment: You should really take a look at the [single file component](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) structure instead of defining every component in one file if you want a to enlarge your application.

Comment: I just became aware of the fact that I obviously down-voted this answer quite some time ago. I have no idea why and assume that I clicked by mistake. However, meanwhile I cannot undo it, my choice is "locked", unless the answer will be edited. So I ask the yuriy636 to edit something in her/his answer so I can undo my stupid downvote. I am really sorry for that!

Comment: Glad you got the message and could edit your answer, @yuriy636! I could turn-around my vote into an up-vote! Thanks for your understanding!

Answer (score 4):

My components was also not rendering.

In case it's not that obvious, like it was to me, take a look at how you are importing components.

For example, first I had:

```
import { CurrencyConverter } from "./CurrencyConverter.vue";
```

And had to remove the brackets, so it looked like this:

```
import CurrencyConverter from "./CurrencyConverter.vue";
```

Ofcourse, this means in your component you use the syntax:

```
export default {
    name: "CurrencyConverter",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just have similar problem.
After I try what @yuriy636 said it still not rendering.
And I found that there is a component declaration in componets field like this:

```
Vue.component('todo-item', {
    template: '<li>This is a list item</li>',
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  },
  components: {
    'todo-item': 'todo-item',  <--- see this ?
  }
})
```

After I remove `'todo-item': 'todo-item'`. It works!

Hope this help other guys!